# Problem with rigging after object rotation

Tags: animation, rigging

I am making a simple door opening animation with door handles pulling down.  Everything worked fine 
[image: Before rotation]

until I selected everything and tried to rotate the door around the Z axis. 
[image: After rotation]

How do i fix this?

Comment: it would be helpful if you would post a ~.blend file, and link to it from your question.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, but I would try to use parenting to make a hierarchy. By doing this you need only to move one object, and the rest will follow.

Note the differences in the outliner:

[image]

Comment: I've edited your post to try and make it clearer. If you disagree with my edits, feel free to roll them back and/or make [additional edits](http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/30939/edit) :)